# What fraction of meteorites found on Earth are for practical purposes non-magnetic?

Tags: meteorite

Of all the meteorites that land on Earth's surface that are let's say pebble to fist sized, what fraction are for practical purposes non-magnetic<sup>1</sup>?

I think the number is around 10 or 20% but so far I haven't found a good source.

One challenge to getting a number is that theres a lot of bias; some people drag magnets around or use metal detectors and will miss the ones with low nickel/iron, and some people look in the top layers of snow in Antarctica and the dark ones might get warmer and sink quicker into the snow/ice.

Therefore with so much bias it might be hard to find a clear, authoritative answer. But maybe there is one.

**Question:** What fraction of meteorites found on Earth are for practical purposes non-magnetic?

---

<sup>1</sup>hold a small pocket or field magnet to it and don't notice any attractive force

Comment: MIght be fun to extend this to all non-orbiting (the sun) objects for which we can estimate atomic content via remote (spectral, etc) analysis.

Comment: What do you mean by *practical purposes* -  What practical purpose do you envisage a meteorite being put to?

Comment: @Chenmunka That's what the footnote attempts to clarify: "practical" in the sense of "practical for someone to test without specialist equipment", as opposed to "chemically provable to exhibit zero magnetism".

Comment: From the way I've heard collectors talk, I'd put it at a fraction of a percent, for ones that are actually found.

Comment: @GregMiller see the "bias" section of my question. Were you able to ascertain from their talk *what methods and methodologies they used to search, collect, and identify* their meteorites? If they were looking for dark metallic chunks with a bit of surface melting, or using a metal detector or dragging magnets behind them, then we can quickly guess that their results are so low for that reason alone.